# Grid over image in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to place a grid with images over a main background image.

I am able to do everything I want so far. And everything works perfectly, except when I resize the browser window.

Here's what I have (don't mind the images. They are for testing):

Max size (grid's relationship to the background image is perfect):
[image: max size]

Medium size (the image to the left is adjusted and goes below, as intendend. The grid's relationship to the background image is still perfect):
[image]

Small size (the grid's relationship to the background image gets completly messed up, and even goes on top of the image below):
[image]

Here's the code:

```
...

    <head>

     ...

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>

            .grid-canvas {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                min-width:100px;
            }

            .foreground_layer {
               position: absolute;
               top: 0;
               right: 0;

               width: 100%;
               height: 100%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container"> <!-- global canvas -->
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="grid-canvas"> <!-- man front canvas -->
                        <img src="./images/man_front.svg" class="img-rounded" alt="Rounded Image">

                        <div class="foreground_layer">
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> <!-- col -->
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> <!-- col -->
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> <!-- col -->
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tile">
                                            <div class="selectable-img"> <!-- -->
                                                @component('components.fss.cog') @endcomponent
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> <!-- col -->
                            </div> <!-- row -->
                        </div> <!-- foreground_layer -->

                    </div> <!-- man front canvas -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="grid-canvas"> <!-- man back canvas -->
                        <img src="./images/man_back.svg" class="img-rounded" alt="Rounded Image">
                    </div> <!-- man back canvas -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- global canvas -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The Cog component is just a simple svg. I need to use it as a component (instead of a raw .svg) so I can do some things I need. It should be irrelevant.

I'm pretty new to CSS and HTML. What am I missing?

Is there another way to achieve this effect?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Isn't this happening because of the .grid-canvas  min-width:100px ?

Comment: No. In fact, if I take it out, the problem gets even worse. The relationship between the two gets messed up even sooner.

Comment: Tried with a fixed:  width:100px ?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want that. I want it to adapt its size to the container.

Comment: Isn't the container the one with min-width set? the .grid-canvas ? btw is hard to fix this without trying, can't create a jsfiddle with the code you provided i tried already. You can make a jsfiddle replacing all the images with something public, and pass the fiddle here on SO so we try to work on it.